# Windows Registry entries of Service User Account keep disappearing

Tags: windows-services, registry, windows-update

I'm writing a *Windows Service*, which runs under a [LocalService Windows Service User Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx).

This service stores some settings [as recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724202(v=vs.85).aspx) in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<CompanyName>\<ProductName>\...`.

(For service accounts [this is actually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software\...`, but that mapping happens automatically.)

This used to work fine. But now these registry entries started to disappear! Why?

Could it be that a major *Windows 10 Update* just removed them? Why? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Hmya, "updates" like the Anniversary and Creator's edition are not exactly updates, they completely reinstall the OS.  The System account belongs to the system and gets recreated at install time.  Probably the best place to store service related keys is in the same place where the service config is stored.  Easy to see with Regedit.exe, navigate to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.  You'll see lots of custom keys and values being used.

Comment: @HansPassant Is that documented somewhere? [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-services-registry-tree) suggests this is for drivers. I'm just writing a service in .NET, not a driver. Should / Could I use `HKLM\Software` instead? Other config data was stored in `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local`. This survived the upgrade. Is that a always "safe"?